# Is there a code to extract complete molecular records from a large sdf file with a list of IDs?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, for-loop, sdf

I am using Phyton 3.7 in  Spider

I try to extract complete molecular records from a large sdf file with an small list of IDs listed in a txt file and writing them into one new sdf file.

More specifically, I have a selected list of about 500 chemical molecule IDs in lines, one ID per line (ten number digits each ID) whose molecular details are contained into a large sdf file of about 2G (300000 molecules, each record contains about 400 lines of code between their ID to the final $$$$ line)

I need  to extract the complete 500 records of the IDs into a single sdf file from the large sdf 2G file for further studies.

I tried the somehow similar and partial python scripts from the stackoverflow and google but not a single one work!
Could anyone give a hint or a few lines of code to test?

Thank you
julio

As suggested (thank you Andrej: great idea), to simplify the problem, I designed small samples of the files. Each line is separated by \n in the originals. I added the positional information to each record to facilitate follow up of results.
f1.txt contains 3 IDs
f2.sdf contains a simplifyed sample of the large 2G data base
f3.sdf contains the desired file, in this case, for the 3 IDs

f1.txt

```
SN00061212
SN00134795
SN00107686
```

f2.sdf

```
SN00039109
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 1 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
$$$$
SN00357061
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 2 in the large sdf list,
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
$$$$
SN00134795
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 3 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
   $$$$
SN00061212
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 4 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN1

```
  $$$$
SN00134796
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 5 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
  $$$$
SN00134795
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 6 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN2

```
  $$$$
SN00333333
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 7 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
  $$$$
SN00145791
  MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 8 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code

```
  $$$$
SN00107686
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 9 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN3

```
$$$$
```

---

f3.sdf

```
SN00061212
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 4 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN1

```
  $$$$
SN00134795
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 6 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN2

```
  $$$$
SN00107686
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D, 9 in the large sdf list
```

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN3

```
$$$$
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample input and expected output. The input can be small example (not complete 400 lines!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module for the task:

If `f1.txt` contains:

```
SN00061212
SN00134795
SN00107686
```

`f2.sdf` contains:

```
SN00039109
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code

$$$$
SN00357061
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code

$$$$
SN00061212
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN1

  $$$$
SN00134796
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code

  $$$$
SN00134795
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN2

  $$$$
SN00333333
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code

  $$$$
SN00145791
  MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code

  $$$$
SN00107686
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN3

$$$$
```

Then this script:

```
import re

with open('f1.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    desired_ids = set(line.strip() for line in f_in if line.strip())

expr = r'({}.*?^\s*\$\$\$\$)'.format(r'^\s*(?:' + r'|'.join(re.escape(i) for i in desired_ids) + r')')
r = re.compile(expr, flags=re.DOTALL|re.M)

with open('f2.sdf', 'r') as f_in, open('f3.sdf', 'w') as f_out:
    for m in r.finditer(f_in.read()):
        print(m.group(0), file=f_out)
```

Produces `f3.sdf`:

```
SN00061212
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN1

  $$$$
SN00134795
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN2

  $$$$
SN00107686
 MOLSOFT 05232012283D

about 400 lines more of code, one in the short txt list SN3

$$$$
```

EDIT:

You can see the regex live on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/E3Yvrd/1)

The `re.DOTALL` means that the dot `.` character matches newlines also. The `re.M` (or `re.MULTILINE`) means, that `^` character will match beginning of the line, not just beginning of the file. More in [official `re` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: @JulioColl I edited my answer. You can see what the regex is doing by clicking on the regex101 link.